# Experiment about a sphere in a tube in presence of viscous resistance

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, pressure, buoyancy, viscosity

Recently, I carried out an experiment at home with little equipment, but I can't get to the bottom of it. Consider a fluid-dynamic resistance force of intensity $F_L$ ($\vec F_L = - \alpha \vec V$) that opposes to the movement at velocity $V$ of a sphere (of radius $R$, homogeneous, density $\rho$) inside an incompressible fluid (water, with density $\rho_W$, contained within a tube of radius $A \gg R$)

1. In my first experiment, the fluid is contained in a tube placed vertically and closed
   below, and the sphere is placed inside the tube at various distances below the upper surface
   of the liquid and left free to move. The sphere left free in the liquid rises to the upper surface; at equilibrium it floats leaving a spherical cap outside the liquid.

I measured the ascent times with a precision of one hundredth of a second (times) as a function of the distance below the surface of the liquid at which the sphere is left (distances). The uncertainty on the distances traveled by the sphere can be considered to be 1 cm. I have reported these values ​​in a table:

$$\small \begin{array}{l|l}
\text{distance  (cm)} & \text{time  (s)}\\
\hline 100 & 1.77\\
200 & 2.85\\
300 & 3.87\\
400 & 4.86\\
500 & 5.87\\
\end{array}$$.

Values are: $\rho_W = 1.000 \ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$; volume of the sphere $V_R = 500 \pm 15 \ \mathrm{cm^3}$; volume of the sphere outside water $V_C = 50 \pm 2 \ \mathrm{cm^3}$

I would like to understand if there is a way (and what it is) to calculate the viscosity coefficient $\alpha$ from these experimental estimates, albeit with relative uncertainty (which one?).

2. Subsequently, I varied the experiment by considering a reserve of the fluid to be contained in a container of cross-section
   much greater than that of the tube considered above. The fluid discharges outwards through the tube (therefore, with an L shape) exiting from a circular opening of radius $a < A$ located at a distance $h$ below the level of the fluid in the container. (So, the total thickness of the tube is $2A$ and the total length of the opening is $2a$).

[image: Geometry of the experiment 2)]
I considered the two hypotheses in which **there is** or **is not** the sphere described above held stationary inside the tube (in the middle). I have noticed that there is a difference in velocity in the two cases. Neglecting the interaction of the fluid with the pipe walls, other forces within the fluid apart from viscous friction, temperature variations and differences in atmospheric pressure, is there a qualitative description of where this difference in velocity comes from in the two cases? Is it possible to calculate the velocity $v$ in the two cases (as a function of the variables expressed) and justify this analytically?

Comment: @Chet Miller Do you have some answers on this?

Comment: Google "Falling Ball Viscometry" for part 1.  Even though your ball is rising (due to buoyancy), the same equations apply.  For experiment 2, I don't understand the geometry.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have modified my original post by inserting a graphic representation of the geometry. Let me know...

Comment: In scenario 2, it is held stationary in the vertical direction, but can move in the horizontal direction?  Why are you omitting viscous interactions with the walll/. It seems that these can be very important.  won't the ball clog the exit hole if it is allowed to move horizontal?

Comment: @ChetMiller In this scenario, the sphere is kept totally stationary. It cannot move either vertically or horizontally, at least I have not thought about what would happen if the sphere moved. So what do you think?

Comment: I think that, if it can not move horizontally or vertically, its velocity is zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller What changes in the two cases where there is the sphere and where there is not?

Comment: I don't understand this question.  I thought the focus was on the velocity of the sphere.

Comment: @ChetMiller The focus is on the speed of the water jet, not the speed of the sphere. That's why we don't understand each other... I would like to determine the velocity of the water flow in the two cases where there is or is not the sphere.

Comment: In scenario 2, neglecting drag by the sphere and the tube wall, the velocity is determined by the Bernoulli equation.

Comment: @ChetMiller There are no frictional forces between ball and wall, but viscous resistance acts according to the law $\vec F = - \alpha \vec V$ as in the first experiment... Also, is there an intuitive explanation of why the two velocities of the water flow are different in the two cases where there is or is not a sphere? A more detailed clarifying answer would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Realistically, you need to consider viscous drag and the proximity of the wall in scenario 2.  The ball acts as a valve, and slows the water flow.  But, unless viscous drag  in the region between the walll and ball is included, you will not predict the lower velocity..

Comment: @ChetMiller OK, you've convinced me... Could you show me how to derive the velocity of the water jet considering the viscous drag in the region between the sphere and the wall in the two cases where there is a sphere and there is not, and why qualitatively there is a difference in velocity in the two cases? An extended answer would be most clarifying.

Comment: I could solve this, but I feel that  it's too much work for a problem you just dreamed up.

Comment: @ChetMiller Why did I 'just dream up'? Anyway, even if it's true that it would be a big job, it wouldn't be a big issue for me, I can understand that. Anytime, if you'd like to dispense some of your knowledge on this, thank you very much!